# RecyclerView scroll to drag and dissmiss

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have overlay view that is animated from top. In that scene i have recycler view with elements list.

When user scrolls list to the end, scrolling further should scroll the whole recyclerview up (uncovering view beneath) and on `ACTION_UP` should animate recycler out of the screen.

overriding onTouch events doesn't work :

1. RecyclerView.setOnTouch() - causes dragging to glitch
2. ParentView.setOnTouch() - works only when dragging other views (not RecyclerView it self).

**It's like new Tinder scroll that uncovers reactions (2017-11-17)**

Any ideas how to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, solved it my self. when i talked about glitching `onTouch` i made a mistake. I set translation to my `RecyclerView`, but i used `MotionEvent.getX()` instead of `MotionEvent.getRawX()` which caused this wild glitch due to inconsistent touch coordinate returned by `getX()`

Also

> recyclerView.canScrollVertically(1);

by Sarthak Gandhi helped.

```
override fun onTouch(p0: View?, p1: MotionEvent): Boolean {
    if (p1.action == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP && dragging) {
        dragging = false
        mInitailPoint = null
        currentDy.invoke(0F)
        return true
    }

    if (p1.action == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN || p1.action == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE) {
        if (!dragging && !recyclerView.canScrollVertically(1)) {
            mInitailPoint = Point(p1.rawX.toInt(), p1.rawY.toInt())
            mCurrentPoint = Point(p1.rawX.toInt(), p1.rawY.toInt())
            dragging = true
            return true
        } else if (dragging && p1.action == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE) {
            mCurrentPoint = Point(p1.rawX.toInt(), p1.rawY.toInt())

            val dy = mCurrentPoint!!.y.toFloat() - mInitailPoint!!.y.toFloat()
            if (dy < 0) {
                currentDy.invoke(dy)
            } else {
                currentDy.invoke(0F)
                dragging = false
                return false
            }
            return true
        }
    }
    return false
}
```

at this point `currentDy.invoke(dy)` actually sets translation to `RecyclerView` of course this isn't complete code to achieve tinder stuff and there is no fling animations, but this part is what the question about.

**Moral of the story: if you set `OnTouchListener` for the view you want to translate - use raw coordinates to calculate translation**

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
  recyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
        @Override
        public void onScrollStateChanged(RecyclerView recyclerView, int newState) {
            super.onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView, newState);
        }

        @Override
        public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
            super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);
        }
    });
```

In the onScrolled method you can translate the whole recyclerView.

To check if you have reached the end then use this method in the onScrolled method

```
recyclerView.canScrollVertically(1);
```

This will return a boolean. Then you can check and move the view.
Hope this helps.

Comment: One problem, onScroll doesn't gets called after reaching end of list.  So i don't know how much i have to move the view.